# Read CSV file to a 2D array on C

Tags: c, file, csv

I have a CSV file , but is separate by semicolon , with integers from 1 to 99 and I'd like to put these numbers on a matrix .I'm using fget() but it don't know how to do to read the hole number (not just 2 and 6 instead of 26)

my code:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    for(j=0;j<100;j++){
        mat[i][j] = fget(rawdata);;
    }
}
```

Comment: `fget`? `fgetc` reads a single character. Look up `fscanf` in your favourite C reference to read entire numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the data is separated by `;` , you can use the `strtok` method of `string.h` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   char buffer[1024] ;
   char *record,*line;
   int i=0,j=0;
   int mat[100][100];
   FILE *fstream = fopen("\myFile.csv","r");
   if(fstream == NULL)
   {
      printf("\n file opening failed ");
      return -1 ;
   }
   while((line=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fstream))!=NULL)
   {
     record = strtok(line,";");
     while(record != NULL)
     {
     printf("record : %s",record) ;    //here you can put the record into the array as per your requirement.
     mat[i][j++] = atoi(record) ;
     record = strtok(NULL,";");
     }
     ++i ;
   }
   return 0 ;
 }
```

Comment: strtol is preferred to atoi

Comment: strtok can be used only if the csv columns are not quoted

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    for(j=0;j<100;j++){
    fscanf(rawdata,"%i",&temp);
    mat[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

thanks to Jongware tip